# Paginated Post List on Front Page

Tags: wp-query, pagination, frontpage

I am trying to get a list of posts on the front page of [thereimers.co](http://thereimers.co/) to have pagination. I am convinced that the code was working when I first launched the site but after checking back a few months later it no longer works. When I click "Next Posts" it brings me to a paginated page but the content that it loads is the same as the front page (minus the hero image which is conditionally set to be different).

One thing to note is I created a custom meta box to select if the post should be displayed on the Front Page or not in case that is relevant.

Anyone have any ideas why this code might not be working? Or perhaps there is a better solution to using a static Front Page template.

```
<!-- Call only 9 posts from Featured category -->
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div class="port-container row">

    <?php
    while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();

        // Retrieves the stored value from the database
        $meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-checkbox', true );

        // Checks and displays the retrieved value
        if( !empty( $meta_value ) ) {
            get_template_part( 'content', 'port' );
        }

    endwhile;
    ?>

</div><!-- .port-container -->

<nav class="post-navigation">
    <div class="nav-prev"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Previous Posts' ); ?></div><div class="nav-next"><?php next_posts_link( 'Next Posts' ); ?></div>
</nav>

<?php else : ?>
    <p>We have not published any stories. Come back soon!</p>
<?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
```

Comment: It looks like I was somewhat misusing the intent of the Front Page based on the WordPress Codex [Creating a Static Front Page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Pagination). A better option might be to use the Home template as my front page.

Comment: So you are using that code where exactly? in a page template attached to a WP *Page* or in `front-page.php`. Also you said it used to work... Have you installed a plugin or made some changes to the code that might be messing /overwriting with your query?

Comment: Pagination query var on a static front page is held in "page", not "paged".

Comment: @bynicolas I was using the code on in `front-page.php` but I think previous I had it setup without `front-page.php` and was using the same code in `home.php` which makes sense now why that previously worked.

@Milo I tried changing it from `paged` to `page` and it still doesn't paginate but I think that may be a limitation of WordPress' static Front Pages.

Comment: It's not a limitation, `paged` should work fine. I believe your customization are overwritten by another plugin/parent theme's function. If you are using a framework to build your theme, it might be setting it's own queries and your changes are not reflected because of that. If you could give us more details on your setup or post the full code of `front-page.php` it might help.

Comment: @bynicolas here's my `front-page.php` file. I tried it again with no plugins installed and it's still not paginating. Do you have any examples of pagination working on a Static Front Page in WordPress? According the Codex it's actually not really possible. I saved my code here: [codepen.io/anon/pen/JNyrJR](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNyrJR)

Comment: the code you posted directly in your question, seems to be ok, apart from necglecting https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query.  the code in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNyrJR is unfortunately in conflict with various recommendations whic you can find in thsi forum, like 'not to use query_posts()' etc...

Comment: @Michael thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I set out to right some of my wrongs in the code and got it working. In this case I think the main thing that fixed my issue was adding `$the_query->max_num_pages` to my `next_posts_link()`. Cheers!